# How to know if a linked list is correctly deleted?

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I got the following algorithm, but I am not pretty sure if the function erase it's the right way to delete a whole list in C, because I am not sure if I correctly free every node of the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lis
{ int n;
struct lis *next;
};

typedef struct lis *list;

void create (list *l)
{
    *l=NULL;    
}

int read (void)
{
    int num;
    puts("ENTER A NUMBER");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    return num;
}

void add (int n, list *l)
{
    list new,previous,current;
    new=malloc (sizeof(list));
    (*new).n=n;
    (*new).next=NULL;
    if (*l==NULL)
    {
        *l=new;
    }
    else
    {
        previous=*l;
        current=*l;
        while ((current!=NULL) && ((*current).n<(*new).n))
        {
            previous=current;
            current=(*current).next;
        }
        if (previous==current)
        {
            (*new).next=*l;
            *l=new;
        }
        else
        {
            (*previous).next=new;
            (*new).next=current;
        }
    }
}

void insert (list *l)
{
int n;
n=read();
while (n!=0)
{
    add(n, &(*l));
    n=read();
    }
}

void print (list l)
{
    if (l!=NULL)
    {
        while (l!=NULL)
        {
         printf ("%d\n",(*l).n);
            l=(*l).next;
        }
    }
    else
{
        puts ("empty list");
    }
}

int isempty (list l)
{
    return (l==NULL);
}



void erase (list *l)
{
    list next;
    list current=*l;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        next=(*current).next;
        free (current);
        current=next;                
    }
    *l=NULL;
}



int main ()
{  
    list l;
    create (&l);
    insert (&l);
    isempty(l)?puts("empty list"):puts("no empty list");
    print (l);
    erase (&l);
    isempty(l)?puts("empty list"):puts("no empty list"); //obviously this return true but just check the header node
return 0;
}
```

Tried to use gdb but I don't even know how to follow the code from a function that is not the main function, and neither how to check if a variable allocated in the heap is free.
So any answer pointing me in the right direction of the use of gdb, or telling me if the code is fine will be appreciated.

Comment: Using Valgrind is your best bet for this type of thing.

Comment: Slightly Related: I'm not just being picky here; throw *away* the `typedef`-ed pointer type. It offers nothing but obscurity to you code, and at this point in your learning curve you *want* to see and manage those asterisks. Seriously. Not kidding.

Comment: I'll take a look at Valgrind, and also will try to implement this without the typedef thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `erase()` is correct, though you could lose one of the pointers and just do this:

```
void erase (list *l)
{
    while (*l)
    {
        list victim = *l;
        *l = victim->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

assuming you did you insertion code correctly and always terminated your list with a NULL, that will be sufficient. Oh, and your add function could be *markedly* reduced:

```
void add (int n, list *l)
{
    list p = NULL;

    while (*l && (*l)->n < n)
        l = &(*l)->next;

    p = malloc(sizeof(*p))
    p->n = n;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
}
```

I leave the error checking for you to implement, but the direct answer to your question is, yes, your `erase` method will wipe out the list correctly provided it is built correctly in the first place.

PS: This: `add(n, &(*l));` can just be `add(n, l);` in the `insert` function.

Comment: great answer, and thanks for the extra info, I'll try this reduced version of the insert function.